# Does leaving a bot game count as an abandon?

Tags: dota-2

I'm unable to access my computer and test this myself now.

If I start a dota game up and it's a bot game, are there abandons? If I leave will I receive an abandon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you are not supposed to get an abandon from a custom bot game (what I assume you are referring to), there is a common glitch that can happen to new players who have't played many pub (public) matches. This glitch results in showing bot games that are left early as abandons and will not put you in low priority but will give you more abandon percentage. 
There is no solution to this glitch but if are playing offline or you play more pub games then the problem will most likely solve itself at some point.
However, if you are just asking if you will get abandons from leaving bot games early, then technically, no.

Comment: Reddit had a post about this. Unfortunately, I can not find it right now.

Comment: @TonySniper Do you remember the general title it was?

Comment: @Chipperyman Unfortunately I don't remember the title right now. Must be something with "Abandon bug lobby" keywords. It has been posted a week ago.

Answer (score 7):

It depend on which kind of game :

- Leaving a matchmaking co-op game versus bot will result in a abandon
- Leaving a custom game (room you made filled with bot) won't result in a abandon.

Hope the difference between the two is clear.

Answer (score 2):

If you are playing an online Co-op bot match then yes leaving will count as an abandon. However if you are playing a local offline bot game that you created of if you are playing a lobby game neither of those count as abandons.

Hope this helps! :)